# SQL get row based on condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi all please see attached data below.  I'm trying to get a row based on various conditions.

scenario 1 - get highest row if no hours exist against it that has (setup + processtime > 0).

scenario 2 - if there's hours (like in this example) show next operation.  (which would be 60).

```
    CREATE TABLE ProdRoute
    ([ProdId] varchar(10), [OprNum] int, [SetupTime] int, [ProcessTime] numeric)
;

INSERT INTO ProdRoute
    ([ProdId], [OprNum], [SetupTime], [ProcessTime])
VALUES
    ('12M0004893', 12, 0.7700000000000000, 1.2500000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 12, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 40, 0.0800000000000000, 0.4000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 50, 0.0400000000000000, 2.8000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 50, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 60, 0.0000000000000000, 0.6100000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 60, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 70, 0.0000000000000000, 1.2900000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 70, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 75, 0.0000000000000000, 3.8700000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 75, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 80, 0.0000000000000000, 0.5500000000000000),
('12M0003571', 3, 0.8900000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 3, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 7, 1.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 10, 0.3000000000000000, 0.3000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 10, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 20, 0.0700000000000000, 0.1000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 20, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 30, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 40, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 50, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 60, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 60, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 70, 0.0700000000000000, 0.1500000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 70, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000)
;

CREATE TABLE ProdRouteTran
    ([ProdID] varchar(10), [MaxOpCompleted] int, [Hours] numeric)
;

INSERT INTO ProdRouteTran
    ([ProdID], [MaxOpCompleted], [Hours])
VALUES
    ('12M0004893', 50, 1.7800000000000000),
('12M0003571', 70, 1.2660000000000000)
;
```

expected output :

```
ProdId  OprNum
12M0004893  60

ProdId  OprNum
12M0003571  70
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by next operation?

Comment: and what defines the highest row?

Comment: oprnum = operation, so the last operation that has work (hours) against it is 50, the next op after this in the prodroute table is 60.  this is the next active operation. highest row is row from prodroute that has setup + processtime > 0

Answer (score 3):

This is just a guess on my behalf, it is not clear to me how you define highest row and next operation:

```
select ProdId, max(OprNum)
from (
    select ProdId, max(OprNum) as OprNum 
    from ProdRoute pr1 
    where not exists ( 
        select 1 
        from ProdRoute pr2 
        where pr1.ProdId = pr2.ProdId
          and pr1.OprNum = pr2.OprNum 
          and SetupTime + ProcessTime > 0
    ) 
    group by ProdId 
    union all 
    select ProdId, min(OprNum) as OprNum 
    from ProdRoute pr1 
    where exists ( 
        select 1 
        from ProdRoute pr2 
        where pr1.ProdId = pr2.ProdId 
          and pr1.OprNum = pr2.OprNum 
          and SetupTime + ProcessTime > 0
    ) 
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from ProdRouteTran prt 
        where pr1.ProdId = prt.ProdId 
          and pr1.OprNum <= prt.MaxOpCompleted
    ) 
    group by ProdId
) as t
group by ProdId;
```

Comment: I have added your query to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12bb3/1 and am getting the correct result... i will need to test this with more examples... thanks!

Comment: apologies the data i gave you for prodroutetran did not match exactly what i had.  I have updated.  ProdRoute.OprNum = ProdRouteTran.MaxOpCompleted http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a588

Comment: I have changed the predicate in my answer, does that help?

Comment: yes i have correct answer now i need to check through other examples.  Thanks very much, get back shortly.

Comment: I have found an order where i am getting no results.  have updated original post data and fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5db2c/1 I would expect to see 12M0003571 70 for this order...

Comment: The fiddle isn't working at the moment but I assume that it is not per ProdId but per ProdId, OprNum. Try add the following predicate to the first two exists clasues: `and pr1.OprNum = pr2.OprNum` and see if that helps

Comment: updated fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c482/2 ... close but am getting 2 results now for previous order... and for some reason my data is showing 60 for order 3571 when is showing 70 in fiddle...

Comment: The different legs in the union contributes with one row each for ProdId = 12M0004893. If you want the larger one you can add an outer select and use max there.